# How optimizeCb in underscorejs work?

Tags: javascript, performance, underscore.js

I've been contemplating this, from [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html):

```
  var optimizeCb = function(func, context, argCount) {
    if (context === void 0) return func;
    switch (argCount == null ? 3 : argCount) {
      case 1: return function(value) {
        return func.call(context, value);
      };
      case 2: return function(value, other) {
        return func.call(context, value, other);
      };
      case 3: return function(value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, value, index, collection);
      };
      case 4: return function(accumulator, value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, accumulator, value, index, collection);
      };
    }
    return function() {
      return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
  };
```

So, apparently this optimization applies only to callback that sets `this` value (here called `context`). How is this different from directly call `call` to the callback? How this is able to improve performance?

It's ok if the optimization is only valid for legacy JS engines. I'm just dying to know.

## Edit

I was probably unclear in the question. This is what I mean. Let's take an example where optimizeCb is used:

```
  _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    iteratee = optimizeCb(iteratee, context); //REMOVE this
    var i, length;
    if (isArrayLike(obj)) {
      for (i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
        iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);
        //REPLACE with iteratee.call(context, obj[i], i, obj);
      }
    } else {
      var keys = _.keys(obj);
      for (i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
        iteratee(obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj);
      }
    }
    return obj;
  };
```

See the 2 comments: `iteratee = optimizeCb(iteratee, context); //REMOVE this` and `iteratee(obj[i], i, obj); //REPLACE with iteratee.call(context, obj[i], i, obj);`. I understand arguments is slow and apply is slow. But I don't see how **arguments** and **call vs apply** come into play here? I see no difference between 2 approaches.

I think the key problem is that if a callback is passed to a certain underscore method, then the signature is already known. For example, callback passed into `_.each` has to have `function(value, index, collection)`. This observation is confirmed in the way optimizeCb is called: if caller of optimizeCb is able to provide the argCount parameter (leave blank means it's 3), it knows which signature it is.

Can someone further elaborate? Many thanks!

Comment: `call` is just a lot faster https://jsperf.com/call-apply-segu . I'm thinking because it doesn't have to access arguments array

Comment: @Moogs: The test you linked to is not comparing apples-to-apples; I think this one does: http://jsperf.com/call-apply-segu/53 There's still a definite advantage to `call` over `apply`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three reasons they might be doing that:

1. Accessing the `arguments` pseudo-array was costly on older JavaScript engines. Really costly. Like, a couple of orders of magnitude costly. :-)

   I don't think there's a huge cost anymore on modern engines, particularly not in strict mode, which removes the live link between `arguments` and formal function arguments.
2. As [Moogs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1439168/moogs) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162941/how-optimizecb-in-underscorejs-work/36163024#comment59963171_36162941), `apply` is slower than `call`. Based on [this test](http://jsperf.com/call-apply-segu/53), looks like it's somewhere between half-again and double the cost. So not in the same league as the order-of-magnitude-or-two of `arguments` (back in the day), but still, faster.
3. If `context` is `undefined`, they return the function unchanged (that's the initial `if (context == void 0) return func;`), so there's no `.call` *or* `.apply` involved at all when calling it.

So what this does is twofold:

A) If the callback doesn't require a specific `this`, it uses the callback directly with a simple function call. If the callback *does* need a specific `this`, they create a function they can call the same way that will use the correct `this`, which saves passing around the `context` argument and simplifies the calling code.

B) They avoid accessing `arguments` and using `apply` for common numbers of arguments by custom-tailoring the wrapper function: Callbacks taking 1-4 arguments get to avoid the cost, callbacks with 0 or more than 4 arguments incur the cost.

Comment: @CharlesW.: Added #3 above.